# Unity IOS game does not pausing on Interstitial ads

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, admob, interstitial

Here is my question;
When I build the game as android target, Interstitials works fine, but when I try the game as an IOS, the Interstitial is shown but the game does not pause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I find the solution

Open your AdManager Script and write this code at Start function;

MobileAds.SetiOSAppPauseOnBackground(true);